# setting up babel with gulp

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I am working though using babel with gulp.   The set up seemed pretty straightforward.  I set up a source folder and created a app.js file

http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#gulp

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app.js")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

However, I am getting errors in the json5.js file from my node modules for various lines when I run gulp.

```
Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected ''
at JSON5.parse.error (/Users/steven/projects/es6/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:50:25)
at JSON5.parse.word (/Users/steven/projects/es6/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:378:13)
at JSON5.parse.value (/Users/steven/projects/es6/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:478:56)
at Object.parse (/Users/steven/projects/es6/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:491:18)
at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/steven/projects/es6/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transf
```

I found my way to the files and cannot understand why some of these are causing errors.

ex:

```
default:
        return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' ? number() : word();
    }
```

I tried to change the quotes to double just to test but am still getting the same error.  Not sure what would cause this.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does ```app.js``` look like?

Comment: app.js is empty right now.

Comment: Sounds like you make have an empty `.babelrc` file?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday and I resolved it by adding a `.babelrc` file in the root of my project.

The `.babelrc` should contain the following content:

```
{
  "presets": "es2015"
}
```

This should allow the `OptionManager.addConfig` to find your `.babelrc` file and your problem should be fixed ;-)